# Are floating point numbers the same in different systems conforming to IEEE754?

Tags: r, postgresql, precision

This is related to my latest question: [What can I do about the difference between real numbers in R versus PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385751/what-can-i-do-about-the-difference-between-real-numbers-in-r-versus-postgresql?noredirect=1#comment81725240_47385751)

I know very little about precision issues and the IEEE754 standard. I read this [link](https://andybargh.com/fixed-and-floating-point-binary/), from which I quote (emphasis mine):

> Because of its wide use, the **format used to store Floating Point numbers in memory has been standardized** by the Institute of Electrical and Electronic Engineers in something called IEEE 754.

To me, that means that if I the number `4104.694` should be equal in two different systems conforming to the standard. However, from my previous question, `R` and `Postgres` seem to represent this number differently:

```
des_num <- 4094.694
sprintf("%.64f", des_num)
# "4094.6939999999999599822331219911575317382812500000000000000000000000"
psql_num <- RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(con, "select 4104.694;")
sprintf("%.64f", psql_num)
# [1] "4104.6940000000004147295840084552764892578125000000000000000000000000"
```

Should I expect the same floating point number to be stored in exactly the same way in different systems conforming to the standard?

Comment: The problem goes even beyond this.  I believe that _within_ R or Postgres, you can see the same number (by same I mean mathematically identical) appearing differently, when certain calculations store that number as a float.  The usual workaround is to use a type which does not suffer from this variation.

Comment: So, I am not talking about calculations. I.e. not, is `1/2` stored the same as `0.5`? I know in this case that precision issues in arithmetic mean that the numbers might not be the same. My problem is, if I store `4104.694` in both `R` and `Postgres`, should I not have the same object when I retrieve it later? (I am trying to work out how to do this directly in postgres but I can't work out how to make postgres print full precision numbers).

Comment: No, not necessarily, because floating point is not exact.

Comment: Ok, that means I have incorrectly interpreted the statement quoted in my OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if R has an exact numeric type, but Postgres certainly does.  Both the `REAL` and `DECIMAL` column types offer exact precision, [see here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html).  If you are working with Postgres as a data store behind your scripts, then if you use real or decimal you should be able to store something from R, and retrieve the exact same thing later on.

Comment: thanks. That seems to be very helpful advice. Although, I am still getting this: `> sprintf("%.20f", RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(con, "select cast(4104.694 as double precision);"))
[1] "4104.69400000000041472958"` which is not the same as printing the same number in `R`.

Comment: @Alex Double precision in Postgres is not exact, and assuming R's numeric type is also not exact, then you could see different things for the "same" number in both places.  Use `real` or `decimal` in Postgres for exact storage.

Comment: Oh, my bad. You wrote `decimal` but I read `double` for some reason. My apologies.

Comment: However, `sprintf("%.20f", RPostgreSQL::dbGetQuery(con, "select 4104.694::decimal;"))` produces the same result as my first comment, and still different to the print in R. So I am guessing that this is because R does not have an exact numeric type.

Comment: I don't know enough about R to comment about what is happening once data enters from Postgres. I'm curious to see if someone else will post about that here

Comment: According to the [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) there is no *exact* decimal type.

Comment: @KevinArseneau Thank you for commenting.

Comment: Thanks @KevinArseneau. Does this mean that `R` does not conform to IEEE754?

Comment: It conforms, but it does not provide the features available within Postgres. I would also note that even in the link provided by @TimBiegeleisen, the precision is to 16383 digits. As with many things... being *exact* is relative.

Comment: @KevinArseneau, According to a web calculator like: http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/, `4104.694` converts to `4104.69400000`. Why does it produce `4094.69399999...` in `R` then, if it conforms?

Comment: Because of [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)

Comment: @KevinArseneau Hmm, so is the binary representation exactly equal in `R` and `Postgres`, but the display method is different?

Comment: @Alex, that is venturing beyond what I know, perhaps someone from *R-core* would need to comment on the internals. There is a [post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/convert-decimal-to-ieee-754-in-r/) that may allow testing the theory.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, for `Postgres`, does "exact" mean conforming to IEEE754, and "inexact" mean not guaranteed to conform? So `numeric/decimal` are the types that conform to the standard, but `float` and `double` are not?

Comment: The standard does not guarantee exact precision, so therefore adhering to the standard is not synonymous with exact precision.